# Dedicated server no space

Tags: vps, centos6, dedicated-server

I have problem with the space in disk , actually i have dedicated server in centos and tell me no space in disk when i use only 19 gb and my disk have 500 gb

I see this when i put df -h :

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                 20G   16G  3.4G  82% /
/dev/root              20G   16G  3.4G  82% /
none                  991M  312K  990M   1% /dev
/dev/sda2             443G  199M  420G   1% /home
tmpfs                 991M     0  991M   0% /dev/shm
```

You can see the size in the hard disk of dedicated server , the system tell me no space for device and running php but my disk have 443 gb free i delete some logs files and win some space in disk but no fix the problem actually because i put other site and continue decrease the space in disk

What can i do for fix this ?

Regards !!!

Comment: This is not really a programming question ([FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)), but you could look into gparted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try log in as root, using for example:

```
su -
```

Then, check how much space are consuming each mount point:

```
du -sh /*
```

Then you can identify where the problem is and try to move the big partition to another place using symbolic links to move specific folders or [moving the folder to other partition](http://linux.chrissweeney.co.uk/topic.php?t=16).

Answer (score 0):

From your df output we can see that you have 2 partitions

> rootfs                 20G   16G  3.4G  82% /
>
> /dev/sda2             443G  199M  420G   1% /home

The problem you're experiencing is very likely caused due to size of your root / partition. As you can see the large part of your storage is mounted in /home, but because PHP, Apache and all other system tools are located in / and when they are started are creating temporary files, log files etc. that's why you're experiencing this error.

The solution here will be to resize your root partition to have at least 50 GB.

You have several ways to do it:

1. Resize / and allocate some space from /home
2. Reinstall the OS and re-partition your OS in the right way.